# Network manager is not listing available wifi networks in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ubuntu-16.04

Not able to connect with the wireless network. I have a healthy wireless driver but don't know what is the problem

```
~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0310]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

~$ dmesg | grep ath

[   28.784514] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   28.784757] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: ath10k_pci_override_ce_config:===wydbg-rev1===change ce5 to OUT
[   28.785560] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   29.616243] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   30.636579] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board id is not exist in otp, ignore it
[   33.115284] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[   33.118193] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   33.118252] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1028:0310) fw WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 6 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.47 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp
[   33.118256] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   33.184478] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[   33.184481] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   33.184483] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   33.184485] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[   33.409422] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   42.566826] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[   42.569733] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  177.334152] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[  177.337150] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  341.113156] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[  341.116070] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  343.646972] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809
[  343.649893] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118

~$ sudo lshw -C network

  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: d8:9c:67:9a:5c:9f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-161-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.250.78 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:282 memory:df000000-df1fffff
```